# Database error during the test: cannot change column

Tags: django

I changed one field of the model, to create migrations and applied it. There were no errors. But when I try to run the tests, there's an error.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1833, "Cannot change column 'rfiid': used in a foreign key constraint 'elements_attachments_rfi_id_bc723558_fk_rfis_rfiid' of table 'test_smap_production.elements_attachments'")
```

field that I changed - **rfiid**. I switched it from **AutoField** to **CharField**.

**models.py**

```
class Rfis(models.Model):
    rfiid = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True)
    ....
```

The migration was successful, and there is no already created instance of the model in the database. Why such an error occurs and how to correct it?

**p.s.**

```
class ElementsAttachments(models.Model):
    e = models.ForeignKey('Elements', models.DO_NOTHING)
    attachment = models.ForeignKey('Attachments', models.DO_NOTHING)
    rfi = models.ForeignKey('Rfis', models.DO_NOTHING)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.IntegerField()
    vendor_response = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Turns out the field is already used as ForeignKey in another table

Comment: @Wariored it didn't help, the mistake was the same

Comment: Show the other model where `Rfis` is a `models.ForeignKey`

Comment: @Wariored Im updated my question

Answer (score 0):

> A not clean way and risky is to delete all previous migrations and make a new migration.

**Warning**: This is risky and can provoke damages if you already have data in your databases.

Comment: I know this way, but I don't think it's right for me.